# How to force dev-dependencies from a dependency to also install with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm currently working on a package (cms), which has a dev-dependency to a certain package (code-generator) to create code. This package is not needed in production.

However, when creating a website that uses the cms package, dev-dependencies (including the code-generator) are not installed (which is correct composer behavior btw).

But while developing the website, the code-generator is required.

Is there any way to force a certain dev-dependency to also install when the package is installed?

Comment: If you need this code generator package, you should add it to your `composer.json`.

Comment: You can run ```composer install --dev```
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: @rob006 yes I could do that, but that means I would need to do that for every site i'm using the package with, plus all the other people that would want to use this package. This is exactly what I want to prevent.

Comment: @DenzylDick That only installs packages defined in the root, not of dependent packages

Comment: See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1763

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Dependency can either be required for the package to work properly (then it should be in `require` section and it is always installed), or required only for development of **this package** (then it should be in `require-dev` section and is installed only when package repository is root). There is nothing in between. If this code-generator dependency is required by your package to *work* it clearly fails into first category (`require` section).

Usually in this case the best solution is to split this package into 2 packages: regular package and `dev` package with all tools used only during development process. So it should be installed by 2 commands:

```
composer require myvendor/mypackage
composer require myvendor/mypackage-dev --dev
```

This will still require everyone to install two packages instead of one, but it should not be a big problem if it is properly documented. Result should is more clear (it should be quite obvious what is the purpose of `myvendor/mypackage-dev` package) and gives more control to package owner (he can easily add new dependencies for `dev` package) and end user (he can always skip installing `myvendor/mypackage-dev` if he don't want to use this code generator).